# Website Thumbnail (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

I have a web page that includes a cropped section of a full size image (thumbnail). 
When the thumb is clicked it opens the full size image.

I wanted to avoid uploading a full size picture and a cropped thumbnail so I used the below class which crops the full size image.

```
.crop { 
 width: 100%;  
 overflow: hidden; 
}

.crop img {
 width: 100%;
 margin: -250px 0 0 0;
}
```

This class gives me the crop of the full size image that I wanted but unfortunately, when I switch from full screen (PC), to mobile the proportions of the image are not kept (The image should look identical on both screens). It looks like the Div width is stretching but the height remains the same.

The full size image is w:650px by h:1000px

The code for my Div is below.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="crop">
            <img src="/Images/5.png" alt="Nil">
        </div>
        <div class="caption" style="padding-bottom: 0px">
            <h4 class="pull-right"><a href="#">#1</a></h4>
            <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: That's a broad question. Are your thumbs being downscaled clientside or serverside? And how exactly?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be much more specific with your question. What've you tried so far? What've you struggled with?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.about.com/od/howto/ss/photoshop_crop.htm#showall

Comment: Do you want to crop the original image instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your image as container background

**CSS:**

```
.Thumb-Box{
display:inline-block;
width: [your width here];
height: [your height here];
}
.Thumb-Box a{
display:inline-block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Thumb-Box" style="background: url('url');background-position: 0px 0px;"><a href="link here">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

"`0px 0px`" stands for what piece of the thumbnail should be seen
ex: `-10px` from `left` and `-10px` from `top`

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
div {
    background: url(img_flwr.gif);
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: this would make the div's background set to the image, so you could set it to be only the top left corner of the image or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You would have to generate the thumb beforehand.
you could do something like this;

```
<a href="http://example.com/img.jpg" taget=_blank>
    <img src="http://example.com/img.thumb.jpg" />
</a>
```

To generate a new thumb, you would have to use some software or lib.